# Data not moving to new shard servers mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have added a shard server to my mongodb cluster. After adding the new shard server, I am getting this error on primary node.

```
DBException thrown :: caused by :: 
CannotImplicitlyCreateCollection{ ns: "config.system.sessions" }: 
request doesn't allow collection to be created implicitly
```

The new shard server is new and did not have any data earlier.

**How did I add the shard server?**

I create a file /etc/mongod.conf (just like my other shard servers)

```
sharding:
  clusterRole: shardsvr
replication:
  replSetName: shardReplicaSet10
storage:
  dbPath: /mnt/mongodb
systemLog:
  traceAllExceptions: true
  path: /mnt/log/mongodb/out.log
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: rename
  destination: file
processManagement:
  fork: true
net:
  bindIp: localhost,172.6.7.5
```

Then I have another member in this replicaSet with same config file, just the bindIp is changed.

I connected to my mongos node and add the replicaSet

```
sh.addShard("shardReplicaSet10/172.6.7.5:27018,172.6.7.6:27018")
```

I can confirm that I have initiated the replicaset using rs.initiate()

Comment: How did you add the new server to the cluster? Better update the question than answer in a comment

Comment: Thanks @noam. I have added the details.

Comment: What is a shard server? A RS node? A complete RS? What primary are you referring to (you should be using a mongos for operations and not any shards directly)?

Comment: Also which MongoDB documentation are you following

Comment: Try `net.bindIpAll: true`. All other shards and all config hosts and all mongos 's need to connect to the shard. I guess `localhost,172.6.7.5` is not sufficient.

Comment: What does the command `sh.status()` return? Please post the output.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that whenever we add a new shard replicaSet, We need to give it a identity manually. I tried the steps given in this answer

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227877

and It worked. On primary of shard replicaSet, simply do this :

```
use admin
```

and add identity

```
  db.system.version.insert({
    "_id" : "shardIdentity",
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5f098ac1077eb0e078fd5c1e"),
    "shardName" : "NameOfYourShardReplicaSet",
    "configsvrConnectionString" : "configReplicaSet/ipofconfigserver:27019,ipofotherconfigserver:27019"
})
```

you can get cluster Id by using

```
sh.status()
```

on any of the mongos cluster.